# Prove: $\sum {{a_{{n_k}}}} < \infty \Rightarrow \sum {|{a_n}| < \infty } $

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Prove:  $$\sum {{a_{{n_k}}}}  < \infty  \Rightarrow \sum {|{a_n}| < \infty } $$

In words, if every sub-series of $\sum a_n$ converges then $\sum a_n$ converges absolutely.
I know that:
$$\liminf\sum {{a_n}}  \le \sum {{a_{{n_{}}}}}  \le \limsup \sum {{a_n}} $$
therefore, $\sum a_n$ is bounded, which implies $\sum a_n$ converges, but it doesn't tell me if the series converges absolutely.

Other direction crossed my mind is splitting the series into two sub-series; odd-indices-series and even-indices-series, but I can't see how it can be helpful in this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: by assumption,  the subseries consisting of *positive* terms converges, and the subseries consisting of negative terms also. Use this to show that the series converges absolutely.

Comment: So, you're saying:  
$\sum {|{a_n}} | \le max(\liminf\sum {|{a_n}} |,\lim \sup \sum {|{a_n}|} ) < \infty $. therefore, $\sum |a_n|$ converges. Is that right?

Comment: @DanielGagnon No, that's not what I'm saying! What I'm saying is that the partial sums of $\sum |a_n|$ are the *difference* of the partial sums of the two subseries that I described. If these two subseries converge, then...

Comment: Oh, I think I get it know. You splitted the series into two subseries: one consists the positive terms, and the other consists all the negative terms. So, the difference is a finite number which is $\sum a_n$

Comment: then, lets say the two limits are $L,M$ then the limit of $\sum|a_n|$ is $|L|+|M|$

Comment: @DanielGagnon That's right!