# Is convergence related to absolute convergence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

So, I saw [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/595769/prove-sum-a-n-k-infty-rightarrow-sum-a-n-infty), and I was wondering, can that assertion be extended to a general complete metric space (or, at least, to something other than $\mathbb{R} $)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you can't take sums in metric spaces, I think that the most natural space to ask this question is a Banach Space. If I understood you correctly, you want to answer the following:

> **Question:** Suppose $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ is a series in a Banach Space $X$ such that every subseries $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_{n(k)}$ converges in $X$.  Does $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \Vert a_n\Vert$ converge?

In that case, the answer is *no*. Let $X=\ell^\infty=\ell^\infty(\mathbb{N})$, the set of all sequences $x=(x_1,x_2,\ldots)$ of scalar (in $\mathbb{C}$, say) such that $\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}| x_n|<\infty$. Eqquiped with the norm $\Vert x\Vert=\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}|x_n|$, it is a Banach Space.

Consider, for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $a_n=(0,\ldots,0,\underbrace{1/n}_{n^{th} position},0,\ldots)$. Then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ is a series in $X$ for which the statement is not true.